# FileInputStream Can't Find File

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am creating a program to play music from a user's computer based on an iTunes playlist file. When I try opening the audio file based on the location provided in the playlist text file, it says there is an error.

```
filename = "Macintosh HD/Users/mporter/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Martin Garrix/Unknown Album/01 Animals (Original Mix).mp3"
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
player = new Player(bis);
```

When I do this, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Macintosh HD/Users/mporter/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Martin Garrix/Unknown Album/01 Animals (Original Mix).mp3 (No such file or directory)` error.

Would it have to do with the `Macintosh HD/Users/` part? Or should I not be using FileInputStream?

Not sure if it matters here but I am using the `jl1.0.1.jar` external Library.

Thanks! :D

Comment: Obvious question: is there such a file at that exact location?

Comment: Yes because iTunes can locate the file.

Comment: I mean, is it rooted at `/Macintosh HD` or something else? I very much doubt you have a folder called `Machintosh HD` at the root of your file system.

Comment: No but I also have a regex to remove the Macintosh HD from the string but i still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the path given to the class.
It seems like you're on Mac, so an absolute path should begin with a '/', not with the name of a drive.

You should probably give to the class something like `/Macintosh HD/Users/...`, or maybe something else if "Macintosh HD" is a drive mounted in a special folder.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The "Macintosh HD" was messing everything up. I tried removing it before with little luck but that was because i forgot the `/`. Thanks!